# Multiply all lights power values at once

Tags: transforms, lighting

So I'm looking for a way to select all my lights in my scene and multiply the power of them by 10000.

They aren't linked as they will have different power and colour settings. I just need to change the wattage as I'm in a crazy large scale for a video game.

I just want to be able to check my lights in blender by scaling up the brightness and back down again. I've tried scaling the world down so the lights are good that way but it causes many issues.

Comment: If you need change all values to the same power - select all lights and for active one change value. Hovering over the value field - right click menu And choose Copy to Selected

Comment: If you need to add Multiply mode And control all lights you would have to share one group in each light materiál ... That sounds late Now fór you ... So you would ask someone with Python knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same amount of numerals to values by holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and click-and-drag value slider left or right. The box becomes blue in this case:

[image]

But I don't know the tricks to multiply values but making the script.

It is not hard in this case, just loop thought selected objects and multiply a value that you can get from context menu "Copy Data Path"

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.data.energy *= 100
```

Copy-paste this text into text editor and press triangle play button to see the effect.

[image]

Comment: that works perfectly! and to put back just change the "*" for a "/" and run the script again for anyone else. Cheers!